Is there a way to frame the detected image?
This project utilizes Apple's visionOS. Currently, the code generates a sphere that tracks detected images. I intend to enhance it by implementing image cropping functionality. This enhancement will transform the detected image into a clickable mesh, signaling interaction.
private func updateImage(_ anchor: ImageAnchor) {
    
    if let existingEntity = entityMap[anchor.id] {
        existingEntity.removeFromParent()
    }

    let imageID = anchor.referenceImage.name
    detectedImageID = imageID
    print("Recognized image with ID: \(imageID)")
    
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
    entity.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
    entity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateSphere(radius: 0.05)])
    
    let material = UnlitMaterial(color: UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.65))
    entity.model?.materials = [material]

    entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    entity.components[CollisionComponent.self] = CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateSphere(radius: 0.05)])
    
    entityMap[anchor.id] = entity
    contentEntity.addChild(entity)

    animateMesh(entity)

    if anchor.isTracked {
        entity.transform = Transform(matrix: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
        entity.isEnabled = true
    }
}


I don't see any usage of the Vision framework here. Did you mean visionOS instead?

yes sorry it is for visionOS
